# Change first key of multi-dimensional Hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have a multi-dimensional hash in perl and I would like to change the first key for a chosen value. For example, I have the hash

```
my %Hash1;
$Hash1{1}{12}=1;
$Hash1{1}{10}=1;
$Hash1{2}{31}=1;
$Hash1{3}{52}=1;
$Hash1{3}{58}=1;
$Hash1{4}{82}=1;
$Hash1{4}{154}=1;
```

Now I want to replace the value 3 in the first key with the value 300. After this I would get:

```
$Hash1{1}{12}=1;
$Hash1{1}{10}=1;
$Hash1{2}{31}=1;
$Hash1{300}{52}=1;
$Hash1{300}{58}=1;
$Hash1{4}{82}=1;
$Hash1{4}{154}=1;
```

I know I could create a new hash by scanning the original hash and doing the following:

```
my %Hash2;
foreach my $key1 (sort keys %Hash1) {
    foreach my $key2 (keys %{ $Hash1{$key1} }) {
        if($key1==3){
            $Hash2{300}{$key2}=1;
        } else {
            $Hash2{$key1}{$key2}=1;
        }
    }
}
```

But is there a quicker way?

Comment: `$Hash1{300} = delete $Hash1{3};`

Comment: You don't need to iterate through the keys of a hash to find a key. That's the point of a hash :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Hash1{300} = $Hash1{3};
delete $Hash1{3};
```

Comment: Great! Many thanks for your help. Turned out to be rather a silly question by the look of it? One day I'll get the hang of hashes!

Comment: `delete` returns the value, so you can `$Hash1{300} = delete $Hash1{3};`